# VirtualFreeEx always returns 0, with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER as last error

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to do some DLL injection with C++.  However, I cannot cleanup my code because VirtualFreeEx always will fail.

here is an example of how I am doing it

```
void *stubBase = VirtualAllocEx(
        hProcess,
        NULL,
        MakeDelta(SIZE_T, DllCallStubEnd, DllCall_Stub),
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if( !stubBase )
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, moduleBase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        delete[] dllBin;
        return false;
    }
```

In this case, moduleBase points to a valid address and was successful.  However, the free always fails.  Also, in another case I want to free a certain memory location (after resuming all processes).  I'll call VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, ImageBase, 0, MEM_RELEASE) and it will also fail with the same error.

Here is my image base before being typecasted:

```
unsigned long ImageBase = ntHd->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
```

Comment: How does moduleBase relate to stubBase?  VirtualFreeEx will fail if you pass it a size of 0 without passing it the base address originally returned from VirtualAllocEx.

Comment: Module base was something allocated earlier.  However, it seems like I found my problem.  My antivirus has hooked VirtualAllocEx and for some reason it is always making it return false.  I will be transferring my project to another machine.